# Pendulum - harmonic oscillator with horizontal displacement?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I was asking myself what happens if one considers not the angular but the horizontal or vertical displacement of the bob as "relevant".

Usually, the angular displacement is considered, leading to the need for small angle approximation for the pendulum to be harmonic.

If one on the other hand considers only the vertical displacement $x$:

[image]

$x$ is the replacement I'm considering $s$ the constant length of the pendulum. The forces are $F_{\text{g}}$ due to gravity, $F_\text{a}$ accelerating the pendulum and the one pointing down and right is stressing the rod.

Now: 
$$\frac{x}{s} = \frac{F_\text{a}}{F_\text{g}}$$

because the triangles are similar and therefore

$$F_\text{a} = \frac{F_\text{g}}{s} \cdot x$$

The force towards the equilibrium is proportional to the displacement.

Now I see what might be the problem: $F_\text{a}$ and $x$ are not parallel and the "non-parallelity" gets worse for larger displacements...

I've removed the "homework and exercises" tag because it is neither.

Comment: Sure, Hooke's law yields an exact harmonic oscillator; In contrast the angular displacement/pendulum is only a harmonic oscillator for small amplitudes.

Comment: Another way to find the period of a simple pendulum is to show that the net force on a pendulum bob is approximately proportional to the horizontal displacement of the bob from its equilibrium position. Is there a typo in the first sentence of your third paragraph?

Comment: I don't see a typo, what do you mean? Also, if x is the horizontal displacement, F ~ x for all possible x, not only for small displacements. I'm speaking of a pendulum hanging from a rod, no springs involved.

Comment: You messed up your trigonometry. The  horizontal component of the net force , which goes like -sinθ, is reduced by cosθ. So $F_x\propto −x \cos(\arcsin(x/L))$, not linear. Now, then, expanding that.... Show your work.

Comment: You really need to show a diagram and your “simple math” if you want further help with this.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay. I've added the sketch and (maybe) answered the question myself. Please consider to un-downvote.

Comment: Two notes: first - glad you added the diagram and were able to solve this yourself as a result; second, when @Farcher asked about your typo, he meant you said "the vertical displacement x" which makes no sense; your diagram confirms you meant horizontal displacement...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you arrived at your result. I think what you are describing is captured in this diagram:

[image]

It is easy to see that the vertical displacement $x=L(1-\cos\theta)$, while the vertical force is a function of both displacement and velocity. The two forces acting on the mass are the tension in the string (green) and gravity (red). When these are not aligned (for any $\theta\ne 0$) there is a net sideways force; but if you are considering the motion of the bob (in a circle) at any point along the arc, you also need to consider the centripetal force needed to keep moving in the arc (there is an additional acceleration term to take into account).

While it is certainly possible to do this, I don't see how you would end up with a simpler expression - and certainly I don't think you end up with "perfectly harmonic" motion regardless of size of deflection.

If I didn't understand your question / setup, please add comments to clarify.

Comment: The (vertical) force is a function of velocity? But only because the velocity is a function of displacement, right?

Comment: The tension in the string is a function of velocity - and this affects both the horizontal and vertical force (because of how the tension and the gravity together provide a net force on the mass that points along the arc; that's how you get acceleration along the arc).

Comment: The [energy derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Simple_gravity_pendulum) , upon trivial variables' changes, also confirms the linearity in h (i.e. x) argument is throroughgoingly specious. The OPs figure is missing the 3rd similar right triangle involved, the one relating $F_a$ with its relevant x-component. Had he only writen this most crucial triangle down, the problem would be reduced to high-school trigonometry.